# ng-click is not working on clicking popup list

Tags: angularjs

i need to call i api when i click on popup items with {ng-click}
i tried but it's not working

```
<div id="popover2" class="hide">
    <ul ng-repeat="clickPopup in clickPopups" >
        <a>
           <u ng-bind="clickPopup.action" ></u>
           <u ng-click="ClickEventShow()"></u>
        <a>
    </ul>

</div>
```

here is my js code...

```
 $scope.ClickEventShow = function() {
    alert("0ooo");
    console.log('qqqq...........');      
};
```

[when i click on lesson on popup item it doesn't fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGv7R.png)

Comment: no error but it doesn't give any response when i click on "lesson" any response

Comment: Since u have used diff <u> tags for binding and click, its not working.Use same tag for both bind and click.

Comment: i tried that too it doesn't work for me

Comment: What is the issue with tht,How u need

Comment: when i click on event which is in blue part of image then popup comes which have the list such as  " lesson ...and more " bt when i click on lesson to call a function it doesn't work.....

Comment: `<u ng-click="ClickEventShow()">Click me</u>`  Jus try this once.. Lets see whether your function is calling or not...

Comment: function is not calling

Comment: Can u replace your images...those are not proper

Comment: jsfiddle.net/g5hdmyhz/25 i need dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You have written:

```
<u ng-click="ClickEventShow()"></u>
```

Change it to:

```
<u ng-click="$parent.ClickEventShow()"></u>
```

I think it might work!!

Comment: Can you please post full HTML and controller code, so I can understand what is going wrong!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6vmjt9rb/126/
here is the code.....apply click function on popoverElement such as rich an all......

Comment: I do not see any of angular code except `ng-click` in fiddle.

Comment: Where did you put the JS code that is written in fiddle? In Angular controller?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you seperate the ng-bind and the ng-click logic into two  tags?

This will work correctly: `<u ng-bind="clickPopup.action" ng-click="ClickEventShow()" ></u>`

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/nXOVwTDHUgdwDcdezJZY?p=info

Comment: i tried 
<u ng-click="$parent.ClickEventShow()"></u>

<u ng-bind="clickPopup.action" ng-click="ClickEventShow()" ></u>


i tried but are not working

Comment: on first click it popup with the list eg:-

lesson

then on clicking on lesson the function is not working


Its not working on Popup list